# How do I get a list of nodes that have a reference to a given user?

Tags: users, 8, nodes

I can get a node's referenced users like so:

```
$users = $node->get('field_allowed_editors')->getValue();
```

But how can I get a reverse list? Getting all the nodes that have a certain user referenced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an entity query:

```
$nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
  ->condition('type', 'article')
  ->condition('field_allowed_editors', $userid)
  ->execute();
```

This will result in an array with all node id's that match the conditions.